# Obter o maior valor numérico informado pelo usuário usando readline

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const readlineSync = require('readline-sync')
const quantAluno = readlineSync.question('Informe a quantidade de alunos: ')
    console.log('Quantidade de Alunos: ' + quantAluno);

for (let i = 0; i < quantAluno; i++) {
    const alunoNome = readlineSync.question('Informe o nome do Aluno: ')
        console.log('Nome:' + alunoNome);
    const alunoNota = readlineSync.question('Informe a nota do Aluno: ')
        console.log('Nota:' + alunoNota);

};
```

Esse é o que eu fiz ate o momento eu eu gostaria de saber como eu vou fazer para puxar a maior nota informada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você precisar salvar todas essas respostas em um objeto.

```js
const notas = {}

for (let i = 0; i < quantAluno; i++) {
    const alunoNome = readlineSync.question('Informe o nome do Aluno: ')
        console.log('Nome:' + alunoNome);
    const alunoNota = readlineSync.question('Informe a nota do Aluno: ')
        console.log('Nota:' + alunoNota);
     notas[alunoNome] = Number(nota);
};
```

Depois, após esse `for` você deve fazer outro loop para conseguir a maior nota obtida e o aluno que a tirou.

```
const maiorNota = Math.max(...Object.values(notas));

for(const [nome, nota] of Object.entries(notas)){
   if(nota === maiorNota){
      console.log("O aluno " + nome + " tirou a maior nota! Nota: " + maiorNota)
   }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!